# Randomising cron jobs in docker containers

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile, cron-task

I have dockerized a springboot java application and running in dev and test environments.

The application has a cron job schedule defined in application.yml.The cron job fetch data from a ESB source and updates its database every 10 minutes.

Now in the dev environment, we didn't had an issue since we had only one container.
In Test environment, since we have multiple containers, all of them are trying to execute the task at same point of time and DB lock messages are being observed.
This also affects the application performance. Cron expression is below

```
services:
  esb:
    applicationId: App-Dash
    schedule:
      job:
        esbprocessing: 0 */5 * * * *
        max_records: ${MAX_RECORDS:20}
```

I have thought of below possible solutions.
  a) Different Cron settings for different containers.
  b) Disabling Cron for some containers.

But Since same docker images are created and shared across different hosts, how is it possible to edit the config file inside a jar file.

Are there any other way to do this.

Comment: You can think of passing environment variable to the containers to enable or disable specific features. In your spring-boot app - check for the flag and take decision..

Comment: I use Rancher to orchestrate docker containers. So I have only one config file and one setting which I use to launch and scale containers. 
Further the setting is defined in application.yml file inside jar file which I doubt can be modified while creating docker image.